# Grouping an array of objects by key in python

Tags: python, fastapi

Suppose I have an array of objects.

```
arr = [
        {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'},
        {'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'},
        {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}
      ]
```

I want this result

```
{
   'A': [
            {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'},
            {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}
        ],
   'B': [ {'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'} ]
}
```

Comment: Your dict is not valid. missing `' '` in keys.

Comment: In python your array is a list and your objects are dictionaries, and you need quotes around grade and name as well

Comment: @Corralien corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dict and `setdefault`:

> **setdefault(key[, default])**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

```
arr2 = {}
for d in arr:
    t = arr2.setdefault(d['grade'], [])
    t.append(d)
```

```
>>> arr2
{'A': [{'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'}, {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}],
 'B': [{'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'}]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) we can do this:

```
import json
gradeList = [
    {"grade": 'A', "name": 'James'},
    {"grade": 'B', "name": 'Tom'},
    {"grade": 'A', "name": 'Zelda'}
]
gradeDict = {}
for d in gradeList:
    gradeDict.setdefault(d["grade"], []).append(d)

print(json.dumps(gradeDict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "grade": "A",
            "name": "James"
        },
        {
            "grade": "A",
            "name": "Zelda"
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "grade": "B",
            "name": "Tom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a simple loop like this:

```py
arr = [{'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'}, {'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'}, {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}]

grouped_grades = {}

for item in arr:
    if item['grade'] not in grouped_grades:
        grouped_grades[item['grade']] = []
        
    grouped_grades[item['grade']].append(item)

print(grouped_grades)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [{'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'}, {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}], 'B': [{'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.groupby

```
>>> keyfunc = lambda item: item['grade']
>>> {k:list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby( sorted(arr,key=keyfunc) , keyfunc) }
{'A': [{'grade': 'A', 'name': 'James'}, {'grade': 'A', 'name': 'Zelda'}], 'B': [{'grade': 'B', 'name': 'Tom'}]}
```

Comment: the 2nd line has an extra ) at the end. 
Other than that, this is exactly the kind of problem that [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) solve

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pd.Dataframe and do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe(arr)    
for index, group in df.groupby('grade'):
    print(group)
```

Instead of print(group) you can write the data to whatever you need it, I suppose it is not necessarily a dict like you described.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to use defaultdict. Then you could convert the result back into an ordinary dict if you need to by simply passing it in the constructor like `dict(output)`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for item in arr:
    output[item['grade']].append(item)
```